# rsync -a always copies some files

Tags: macos, rsync, ext4

I have a cron job that backs up files from a remote server (Ubuntu, ext4) to my local machine (OS X, hfs+) nightly using `rsync -a`.  Everything works fine but there are a few files that are *always* copied regardless of data modified timestamp.  Even if I run it back to back all the unchanged files are skipped as expected except these select few files.

The timestamp has definitely not changed and nothing has been modified in these files.  The ownership, permissions, etc are all identical as far as I can see, but rsync still insists on overwriting them every single time the job is run.

What would cause this?

**UPDATE:**
It appears this has something to do with HFS+ being case insensitive vs EXT4 and occurs with directories having uppercase characters.  Building rsync with case-insensitive option is not realistic as this job is running on many different servers.  If anyone has a viable workaround that would be great.

Comment: Are only directories with uppercase showing this behavior or files too?

Comment: it seems to be both. see my answer below - it's definitely a matter of case sensitive file system differences

Comment: You could create a case-sensitive `.dmg` and mount that as volume perhaps. I haven't tried the `-y, --fuzzy` option in rsync either, so that might be worth looking at too.

Comment: yes i considered that.  it's a good idea but There is other content on the volume and the whole thing needs to be a bit more dynamic.  i tried `-y` but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I used iParition and converted my HFS+ volume to case-sensitive.

I am still interested in a viable answer which does not require altering partitions.